# Defining Leaflet map as dynamic map id (Cannot read property '_container' of undefined)

Tags: leaflet, containers

I have 2 different divs which using by leaflet as map object. I want to define my map objects into a function such as

html

```
<div id="mymap"></div>
<div id="mymap2"></div>
```

javascript

```
var map;

function define_map(map_id) {

  var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
      maxZoom: 7
    }),
    map = new L.Map(map_id, {
      center: new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.04),
      zoom: 7
    }),
    drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
});

define_map("mymap");
define_map("mymap2");



$(".btnmarker").on("click", function() {
  console.log(map); 
  L.DomUtil.addClass(map._container, 'my_crosshair-cursor-enabled'); // ON THIS LINE GETTING ERROR CODE Cannot read property '_container' of undefined
  selected_tool = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

There is no problem, my maps seems working good until accessing features of them from button click event (this button will add a marker class to a map which i clicked on it)

But i'm getting map is not defined error. map is a variable and defined on top line of page.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: Do you see the maps right now when you call `define_map`?

Comment: yes. seeing without any problem. I don't want to write tons of multiple code when i define a new map object. I just want to add a function and call it when i define a new map object. simple as this.

Comment: `map` isn't defined until the `map = new L.map(...)` call. As the error says, `map._container` doesn't exist until then.

Comment: @peeebeee but as ytou can see i already have `code`map = new L.map(...)`code`  call in myfunction.